# Having VBA only run if dates of two different cells are different

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have been running through endless pages of stack overflow pages that have answers similar to this, but none have worked.

What I am trying to do is have VBA either archive data or not - depending on when the data was last archived. At the end I am hoping my code will:

1. Pull the last date of the archive and place it into cell H16 (complete)
2. Compare the current day to the date pulled in step 1
3. Archive the data (i.e. run the program) if the two days are different
4. If the two dates are the same, exit the sub and display a message box saying so.

So far I have:

```
'VBA Archive Check
If Range("H16") <> Date Then
    GoTo Start

ElseIf Range("H16") = Date Then
    GoTo ExitSub
End If

'ExitSub
ExitSub:
MsgBox "Current Day Has Already Been Archived"
Exit Sub
```

Let me know if additional context is needed!

Thanks all.

Comment: Woops! Posted the code in incorrectly. It has been updated

Comment: So what exactly is the issue now? Note that normally the use of `GoTo` is frowned on as it tends to create spaghetti code.

Comment: I figured it out! It was referencing a merged cell, which caused it to act weird. Curious to understand why GoTo is bad - im new to VBA but will take a look!

Comment: Research "spaghetti code."

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to reference an un-merged cell. This code should work

'VBA Archive Check
If Range("Enter Cell Here") <> Date Then
GoTo ______

ElseIf Range("Enter Cell Here") = Date Then
GoTo _____
End If

'_______
ExitSub:
MsgBox "Current Day Has Already Been Archived"
Exit Sub